# Clear SQL Server Buffer after SSIS is done?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm new...

I've built an ETL process in SSIS that takes 46 flat files and loads them into stg.Suppliers and triage.Suppliers.  Then another solution runs that applies Business Rules.  And then the final solution moves the good stuff from stg.Suppliers into pdw.Suppliers.

My question is when I run all this (once a week); is it good (best practice) to clean up the buffer for the stg.Suppliers table?  I notice that when I run this [query](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlperf/2007/05/18/whats-swimming-in-your-bufferpool/) that it's the number one cached_pages_count.

If yes, how?

Comment: What Max said. Also, if you have enough disk, don't empty the staging tables until the next run 'cuz you never know when you'll find a bug and there's no need to rerun the whole ETL if you don't have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving it in cache will have no downsides since SQL Server does a great job managing the cache without interference.  In fact, it may be beneficial to keep some of those pages cached.

Are you attempting to solve some problem?